# Resharper solution settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

I have Visual Studio with Resharper 7.1 configured in it. I opened a solution and added a word say `QWERTY` in the abbreviation list. I could find this entry in `GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings` file and everything is working as expected.

Now I deleted this abbreviation entry from `GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings` file. Now also I am able to see the abbreviation word in the solution as valid through Resharper. Then I checked my `mySolution1.DotSettings` in my solution's folder and could not find this entry here as well. Can any one help me to understand where this abbreviation is actually stored? Also what are the places where resharper settings are actually stored?

Comment: Did you try clearing ReSharper's cache? (ReSharper > General > Clear Chaches)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try "Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# Naming Style -> Advanced Settings"?

There you should find the textbox named as "**Abbreviations as plain text (UPPER CASE only)**" below the page. From there, just remove the word that you added accidentally to this list.

Hope it works!

Comment: I know this thing. But problem when I open my solution then those word are listed in the textbox you mentioned. Opening this window in some some other solution does not show these words.

Comment: I just dont want to remove these words from my solution, I actually want to know where these are stored. I have some further plans to execute based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper stores these words in 3 separate files based on the user preference:

1. **mySolution1.DotSettings** (Project specific)
2. **mySolution1.DotSettings.user** (Project specific)
3. **GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings** (Global)